# Firestore emulator gets document form cache after document write that is rejected due to security rule

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I have Flutter mobile application in the front end and Firebase in the backend.  I am currently running Firebase emulator.  I am using Firestore for storing data.

I have a QUERY that is supposed to fetch a document and a WRITE that is supposed to update the document.  When I run both the QUERY and WRITE in the following order I see a bug.  Is there a solution.

1. Run the QUERY to read the document from Firestore.
2. Run the WRITE to update the document in Firestore. The WRITE fails because of a security rule which is what I expect.  The document in Firestore is not updated also as expected.
3. Run the QUERY to read the document from Firestore.  This time, the value read is the value in step 2 even though the write has failed.  When printing the Metadata over here, I find that isFromCache is false but hasPendingWrites is true.

It seems to me that the write in step 2 updated the cache and the read in step 3 read the doc from the cache giving me wrong results.

Any idea if this is a bug in Firestore emulator or if I should be doing something else?

This is the WRITE code:

```
await _firestore.doc(PathService.boosts(uid)).update({
      'boosting': true,
      'boosts': FieldValue.increment(-1),
      'endedAt': Timestamp.fromDate(
        DateTime.now().add(const Duration(hours: 1)),
      ),
      'ttl': Timestamp.fromDate(
        DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 7 * 365)),
      ),
    });
```

Here is the code for the READ.  I tried to use Source.server hoping to force the READ from server instead from cache but did not work:

```
    _firestore
        .doc(PathService.boosts(uid))
        .withConverter<MyProfileBoosts>(
          fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) {
            return MyProfileBoosts.fromJson(snapshot.data()!);
          },
          toFirestore: (myProfileBoosts, _) => myProfileBoosts.toJson(),
        )
        .get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server));
```

As for the Firestore security rules, all you need is simple rule that makes the write fails.

Comment: I am on android emulator with firebase emulator suite, Sometime emulator just didn't sync data for me, But after recent update seems getting better.

Comment: I have the latest Firebase emulators as well.  But still this problem exists.

Comment: It's hard to be certain without seeing an actual [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but this could be working as designed. Firebase SDKs fire events for local writes optimistically, so the write could be triggering a listener before the write hits the "server" and security rules are enforced. But as said, it's hard to be certain without the code to repro the behavior and something like logging output that shows the exact order of operations.

Comment: I have updated the post to show the code for the READ and WRITE.